# Proof of Chapman-Kolmogorov equations for the general case

Tags: integration, markov-chains

I've started studying Markov Chains, but I'm fairly new to the topic and I don't follow some of the reasonings done  in the books I'm reading, especially those related with integral manipulation, For example, in Meyn and Tweedie's Markov Chains and Stochastic Stability, 2nd edition, page 61 they state:

> **Theorem 3.4.2.** For any $m$ with $0 \leq m \leq n$,
> $$
> P^n(x,A)= \int_X P^m (x,dy)P^{n-m}(y,A), \quad x \in X, \ A \in \mathcal{B}(X)
> $$
> *Proof:* In (3.20), choose $\mu = \delta_x$ and integrate over sets $A_i = X$ for $i = 1, \dots, n-1$, and use the definition of $P^m$ and $P^{n-m}$ for the first and last $n-m$ integrands.

I'm not sure how to prove the result from the hint. Equation (3.20) appears in theorem 3.4.1, which reads:

> For any initial measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal{B}(X)$, and any transition probability kernel $P=\{P(x,A),x \in X, A\in \mathcal{B}(X)\}$, there exists a stochastic process $\Phi=(\Phi_n)_{n \geq 0}$ on $\Omega = X^{\infty}$ measurable w.r.t $\mathcal{F}=\vee_{i=0}^{\infty}\mathcal{B}(X)$ and a probability measure $\mathbb{P}_{\mu}$ on $\mathcal{F}$ s.t $\mathbb{P}_{\mu}(B)$ is the probability of the event $\{\Phi 
>  \in B\}$, and for measurable $A_i \subset X$, $i=0,\dots, n$ and any $n$:
> \begin{align}
>  &\mathbb{P}_{\mu} (\Phi_0 \in A_0  \dots , \Phi_n \in A_n )
>  \\= &\int_{y_0 \in A_0} \dots \int_{y_{n-1} \in A_{n-1}}\mu(dy_0)P(y_0,dy_1)\cdots P(y_{n-1},A_n) ,
> \end{align}

According to the hint in theorem 3.4.2, we should take
$$
\mu =  \delta_x (y)= \begin{cases}1 & \text{if  } y = x;\\
0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}
$$
and $A_i = X$ for each $i$, so the LHS would read:
$$
\mathbb{P}_{\mu} (\Phi_0 \in A_0  \dots , \Phi_n \in A_n ) = \mathbb{P}_{\mu} (\Phi_1 \in X  \dots , \Phi_n \in X \, | \, \Phi_0 = x),
$$
Now I don't really know how to plug into the integral in the RHS the fact that $\mu = \delta_x$ and conclude the result from here.

The definition of the kernel $K=P$ and $P^m$ is the following:

> A transition kernel over a measurable space $(E, \mathcal{F})$ as a map $K: E \times \mathcal{F} \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ s.t. $K(\cdot, A)$ is measurable for each $A \in \mathcal{F}$ and $K(x, \cdot)$ is a measure for each $x \in E$, and a transition probability $K=P$ as a kernel s.t $P(x,E) \leq 1$. After this we have defined $K^n$ by induction setting $K^0(x,A) =\mathbf{1}_A (x)$ and $K^n = KK^{n-1}$, where:
> $$
> K_1 K_2 (x,A)=\int K_1(x,dy)K_2(y,A),
> $$

Comment: It is probably not the best idea to jump into the general case when one starts to study Markov chains. Advice : take the much more tangible heat kernel (wikipedia) and do some integration to show that it constitutes a semigroup. Then study the Kolmogorov theorem where it is shown how the Wiener measure is constructed.

Comment: @KurtG. yeah fair enough. The thing is that I am currently doing some work on Monte Carlo Markov Chains algorithms, which often involve Markov Chains taking values in continuous spaces, so I wanted to learn stability results etc. that are applicable for the continuous case too. Thanks for your advice!